# Support OAuth 1.0 (amd 1.0 a) support in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: oauth, zend-framework2

Is there any official support for OAuth 1.0 in ZF2 ? I checked the documentation and couldn't find much information. I see a thread : [OAuth in Zend Framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942503/oauth-in-zend-framework-2) that talks about it but when i downloaded the full distribution - https://packages.zendframework.com/releases/ZendFramework-2.2.2/ZendFramework-2.2.2.zip, i couldn't find the OAuth package unless i am missing something. Please advise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OAuth in Zend Framework 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942503/oauth-in-zend-framework-2)

Comment: The ZF zip file only includes the core libraries. You can get additional packages (including the OAuth lib) as detailed in the question above.