# how to use Zend 2 Oauth package

Tags: zend-framework2, oauth-2.0

thanx for reading, this is the first time I try to use zend 2 with Oauth, following the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12944767) I did as it said using composer but I don't know how to check if it's really installed.
how can I check if it's installed? And how to use it? I tried in index controller to call it like examples in [zend page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zendoauth.introduction.html)

```
$config = array(
    'callbackUrl' => 'http://example.com/callback.php',
    'siteUrl' => 'http://twitter.com/oauth',
    'consumerKey' => 'gg3DsFTW9OU9eWPnbuPzQ',
    'consumerSecret' => 'tFB0fyWLSMf74lkEu9FTyoHXcazOWpbrAjTCCK48A'
);
$consumer = new ZendOAuth\Consumer($config);
```

but it returns:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Application\Controller\ZendOAuth\Consumer' not found
```

and tried to include it at the top using `use` command but can't find any package named Oauth.
Can any one help me with this?
any idea or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You're within the `Application\Controller` namespace, so when you do `new ZendOAuth\Consumer`, PHP assumes you mean `new Application\Controller\ZendOAuth\Consumer` unless you tell it otherwise.

To fix the error, you need to do:

```
$consumer = new \ZendOAuth\Consumer($config);
```

However, you may have trouble getting this working, as I'm 80% sure the Zend OAuth package only supports OAuth 1 (it's it's just a port of the ZF1 package), not OAuth 2.

Comment: Thank you @Tim Fountain the error is gone, please can you explain to me what does it mean when you add this back slash?

Comment: The initial backslash means use the global namespace, instead of the namespace you're currently in.